# FFMPEG Compile Custom

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, compilation, cross-compiling, libavcodec

I need to compile FFMPEG with version 2.1.8 of source and with the following options -

```
./configure --arch=x86 --target-os=mingw32 --cross-prefix=i686-w64-mingw32- --cc=i686-w64-mingw32-gcc --disable-postproc --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-decoder=libvpx --disable-encoder=aac --enable-avisynth --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-pthreads --enable-avfilter --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-nonfree --pkg-config=pkg-config --enable-libquvi --enable-libfaac --enable-libnut --enable-libgsm --enable-libfreetype --enable-libvorbis --enable-libspeex --enable-libmp3lame --enable-zlib --enable-libtheora --enable-bzlib --enable-libvpx --enable-libxvid --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libschroedinger --enable-librtmp --enable-libass --enable-libx264 --enable-libbluray --enable-openssl --enable-libflite --enable-libsox --disable-ffplay --enable-libcdio --enable-libcelt --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libxavs --disable-outdev=sdl --disable-muxers --enable-muxer=encx --extra-cflags=-I/usr/i686-mingw32/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/i686-mingw32/lib --extra-libs='-lx264 -lpthread -lwinmm -llua -liconv -lcurl -lws2_32 -lssl -lcrypto -lwldap32 -lgdi32 -lwsock32'
```

I need to know on which system will be good to compile this ?

also some libraries might be obsolete so where can I find them ?

Please provide your input how would you compile it ?

The configuration was extracted from a custom version of avcodec-55.dll , need to demux a video using new compiled ffmpeg.

Regards

Comment: Hi how do I place in the config options ? Do I have to edit the script. You are the script author it seems.

Answer (score 1):

recommend http://github.com/rdp/ffmpeg-windows-build-helpers which builds the dependencies for you

appears it would be `--build-ffmpeg-shared=y  --build-ffmpeg-static=n --ffmpeg-git-checkout-version=n2.1.8` it will complain of some newer dependencies it doesn't understand (like --enable-decklink) so just remove those flags from inside the script and run again, gl!

Comment: Hi where do I add "--enable-muxer=encx" ?  If you can , can you edit the script and show me here.

Comment: On changing the config_options="$ the following eror comes - 

./cross_compile_ffmpeg.sh: line 1694: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./cross_compile_ffmpeg.sh: line 1694: `  echo "your box only has $box_memory_size_bytes, 512MB (only) boxes crash when building cross compiler gcc, please add some swap" # 1G worked OK however...'

Comment: @MadskillzRCE if that muxer is enabled typically it'll already be enabled.  If the script worked OK before you change then I'd start with a fresh copy and try again, GL!

Comment: The first time I ran I got the --enable-decklink error as you said , then I changed the configs and got the above error. So I create a new dir and start fresh but I can change the config before executing the script right ?

Comment: BTW this is the config I used - http://pastebin.com/J6XzNnqp and excuted script like this right now - ./cross_compile_ffmpeg.sh --build-ffmpeg-shared=y  --build-ffmpeg-static=n --ffmpeg-git-checkout-version=n2.1.8 , will i require to build any sources of any other dependencies ?

Comment: libsox
-lpthread
-lwinmm
 -llua
 -liconv
 -lcurl
 -lws2_32
 -lssl 
 -lcrypto 
 -lwldap32 
 -lgdi32 
 -lwsock32
 
libbluray
libcelt
libnut
libquvi
openssl
libcdio-paranoia     I had to delete these for compiler to run , maybe one or two more I did not copy the names. How to add them to script to install

Comment: also getting libavutil.pc not found

Comment: It used to have that but quvi support was removed from ffmpeg, so I guess you could revert back to when it did, but GL there...

Comment: I am using source  FFMPEG version 2.1.8 , which the dll used , so I guess it will be supported

Comment: http://www.filedropper.com/ffmpeglibraries - check this. , I need to create ffmpeg of these libraries , the config was extracted from here,

Comment: I suppose if you have a problem with the command I gave you, file it as a github issue for that project. My last comment here, cheers!